# How can I ensure my spinner (inside menu) updates my menu title and ensure the title is displayed in full?

Tags: java, android, android-xml, android-menu

**Edit: Upon Re-setting the emulator the code is working fine and the title updates instantly when a spinner item is selected. However, the title is still not being displayed in full**

**Edit 2: Upon Re-setting the emulator once more I am having the same issues again...**

I have tried to implement a spinner inside my menu for my `recordExerciseActivity`.

[image: recordExerciseActivity]

Every time an item inside the spinner is selected, this is set as the new menu title.

The problem I am having is that the first time I open the activity and click on a spinner item the title is not updated. (The `onItemSelected` code does not run)

However, the second time it works perfectly fine.

Moreover, in activities which the exercise names are really long, it only displays the first few letters.

[image: 2]

Sometimes only the first letter...

[image: 3]

How can I ensure the spinner updates my menu title correctly every time?
(displaying the full title as well).

**Menu XML**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="spinner Title" />
</menu>
```

**RecordExerciseActivity**

```
public class RecordExerciseActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<String> allChildExerciseNames = new ArrayList<>();
    public static final String PARENT_EXERCISE_ID = "-999";
    public static final String EXTRA_DATE = "com.example.exerciseappv4.EXTRA_DATE";
    public static final String EXTRA_WEEK_DATES = "1";
    public static String EXTRA_JUNCTIONID = "EXERCISE_JUNCTION_ID";
    int parentExerciseID;
    private ChildExerciseViewModel childExerciseViewModel;
    String firstExerciseName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_record_exercise);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent.hasExtra(PARENT_EXERCISE_ID)) {
            parentExerciseID = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra(PARENT_EXERCISE_ID));
        }

        BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.top_navigation);
        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container2, new RecordExerciseFragment()).commit();

        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_back);
        childExerciseViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ChildExerciseViewModel.class);
        childExerciseViewModel.getChildExerciseNameFromParentID(parentExerciseID).observe(this, this::setChildExerciseName);
        childExerciseViewModel.getAllchildExercisesFromParentID(parentExerciseID).observe(this, this::getAllChildExercisesFromParentID);

    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.nav_track:
                            selectedFragment = new RecordExerciseFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_history:
                            selectedFragment = new RecordExerciseHistoryFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_exercise_list:
                            selectedFragment = new ExerciseGraphFragment();
                            break;
                    }
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container2, selectedFragment).commit();

                    return true;
                }
            };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.record_exercise_menu, menu);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.spinner);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) item.getActionView();
        ArrayList<String> spinnerStringArray = new ArrayList<>();
        //Add your data to your array
        spinnerStringArray.addAll(allChildExerciseNames);

        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, allChildExerciseNames);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);


        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.i("Spinner Item Selected", "TRUE");
                String selectedExercise = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                setTitle(selectedExercise);

            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
        return true;
    }

    private void setChildExerciseName(String childExerciseName) {
        firstExerciseName = childExerciseName;
        setTitle(firstExerciseName);
    }

    private void getAllChildExercisesFromParentID(List<String> allChildExercisesReceived) {
        allChildExerciseNames.addAll(allChildExercisesReceived);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you getting any error while updating the first time?

Comment: I don't see `setTitle` method implementation

Comment: There is no error the first time, it just does nothing.

Comment: The setTitle is called in the menu.

Comment: Where is the method `setTitle()`?

Comment: I call the built in setTitle method inside `setChildExerciseName` method and inside `onItemSelected`.

Comment: Log a message in the `onItemSelected` and see if it gets called, first time or second time.

Comment: The `onItemSelected` method is not run the first time, but only for the first exercise in the list. If I press back and retry again, it runs. For all of the other exercises in list, the `onItemSelected` is being run as soon as the activity opens and there is no problem (apart from the title text not being fully displayed).

Comment: Add the screen shots to the question not as a link, is the title lengthy?

Comment: Yes the title is lengthy (sometimes) however, I believe the spinner is messing with it.

Comment: Just tried to reproduce - couldn't make it, works ok on my machine. Running on Pixel 2 emulator API 28.

Comment: I have ran the app on 3 different phones and they are all having the same problem. (The title doesn't always update and is getting cut off short). What would you recommend I do to determine the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this custom `layout` file for your `Spinner` :`simple_spinner_item_custom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/custom_text_1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:textAlignment="inherit" />
```

This is the simple modification of original `simple_spinner_item.xml` file to make it work in your scenario with editing attributes such as `android:singleLine="true"` and `android:ellipsize="marquee"` which wouldn't let you show multiline text.
Now, pass this layout as the argument in the `ArrayAdapter` constructor as :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                R.layout.simple_spinner_item_custom, spinnerStringArray);
```

**Note:**
There is no point in setting title of the `Activity` using `setTitle()` method. Thanks to the new `LiveLayoutInspector` feature in Android Studio 4.0, I found out that this `Spinner`(so will its parent i.e `ActionMenuView` ) will be stretched to fit the content inside it and `title` of `Activity` will be sandwiched. I tried to reduce the `width` of `Spinner` or `ActionMenuView` with no success. Sadly, this way, I think your back navigation button will also be hidden.[image: Sandwiched title of the Activity Window]
[image: Stretched Spinner]

But again, if you use `app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"` attributes to the `Spinner`menu, you will get more or less similar kind of UI.
Play with such attributes until they fit into your need.

Another **alternative** that I can think of at this moment is to `inflate` a normal `menu` with down arrow as `icon`, then in `onOptionsItemSelected`, handle it to open a `Popup` menu which will show the list of items that currently your `Spinner` is showing. Then, handle the `onClick` of `Popup` again to change the title of `Toolbar`(because the `title` of `Activity` doesn't support multiline and it doesn't have any `id`, so that its object can't be created).

Comment: I have made the change which you suggested, however the onItemSelected method is no longer working as it should. The spinner drop down works perfectly fine, however when I click on a spinner item, the change is not made and I get this message:  
            `D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0xc677c450 (DropDownListView) with handle 0xc6e90910`

Comment: `onItemSelected()` method is no longer needed to be handled as long as we handled the `onItemSelectedListener()` of `spinner` menu. Move the code from `onItemSelected()` to `onItemSelectedListener()`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, unless you explicitly tell android studio to call onCreateOptionsMenu at the onCreate of the Activity, it does not do so until the menu buttons are actually interacted with.
So what is happening here is that when you are selecting it for the first time Menu is getting created but onClick is not getting registered.

Just adding a call to the `onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)` at the end of the onCreate function of the Activity that should fix it.